# The master method - why can't it solve T(n) = T(n/2) + n^2/logn?

Tags: algorithm, master-theorem

The master method - why can't it solve T(n) = 4*T(n/2) + (n^2)/logn?

I realize it can solve recurrences of type T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)

On MIT OCW they mentioned that it couldn't solve the above recurrence though. Can someone provide an explanation as to why?

Comment: Could you provide a link to where they say it can't be solved? Also, is it (n^2)logn or n^(2logn)

Comment: Not really a programming question. The Master Theorem soves *some* recurrences of type T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n), but not all. There are restrictions on `a`, `b` and `f` which your example doesn't satisfy (presumably -- I haven't worked it through myself but if MIT says so then it's probably right, and if MIT is wrong then your question is moot!). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_Theorem for more details, or I imagine you can find the same information and more, somewhere in MIT's material.

Comment: ... and if your question is "why are there restrictions on `a`, `b`, and `f`", then I suppose really you need to consult a proof the Master Theorem, to understand where the restrictions are necessary to get the results out.

Comment: That looks like third case of master theorem.

Comment: Sorry guys, edited it to (n^2)/logn and changed the T(n/2) to 4*T(n/2) though the latter doesn't make any difference I think.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yeah I think I need to read up about why there is a restriction on f, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Answer for T(n/2) + (n^2)/logn:

```
Case 1 does not apply because f(n) != O(n^-e) for any positive e.

Case 2 does not apply because f(n) != Θ(log^k(n)) for any k >= 0

Case 3 does not apply,
    f(n) = Ω(n^e) for e = 1, BUT
    a*f(n/b) <= c*f(n) for no c<1 (works out that c >= 2)
```

So we can't apply any case. Beyond this I'm no good really - and again I'm not 100% on this answer.

---

The following was prior to this edit, and assumed the question was with regards to T(n) = T(n/2) + n^(2logn)
I'm fairly sure that it is case 3 of the theorum.

```
Case 1 does not apply because f(n) != O(n^-e) for any positive e.

Case 2 does not apply because f(n) != Θ(log^k(n)) for any k >= 0

Case 3 does apply,
    a*f(n/b) <= c*f(n) for some c<1 (works out that c >= 0.5)
    and f(n) = Ω(n^e) for e = 1
```

I may be wrong so check it and let me know!

Comment: I edited the question slightly (put in some brackets so it's clear what is divided by what and what is raised to what) so hopefully it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

f(n)=(n^2)/logn and n^(log a/log b) . Compute the difference between the above two functions.

ratio= (n^2/log n)/(n^2)

The ratio turns out to be logarithmic. This recurrence relation falls in to the gap between case 2 and case 3. So Masters theorem is not applicable for this recurrence relation.

Masters theorem is applicable when the difference between the two functions stated above is polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

its because in all the mentioned three cases you can't justify the positive asymptotic nature. which means when n->infinity n^2/lg(n) -> infinity, that simply implies n^e = w(lg(n)), Which can be paraphrased as "the function can not be contained" no upper bound exists for dividing and conquering procedures.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the 3rd case as f(n) is greater but it should also satisfy the regularity condition (af(n/b)<=cf(n) for some c in(0,1)).
Here the function is not satisfying the regularity condition so master method fails here